# Transfer an id via parameter in an html form

Tags: php, html, forms

Good morning to you all,

I would like to transfer to my target page an id that I have upstream recovered with GET, in the sending form with a php parameter,

```
    <?php $idEleve = $_GET['id']; ?>
    <form method="POST" action="addNotes.php?id=$idEleve">
```

I’m not sure it’s okay, please help me

Comment: Did you try it?? It looks good to me !!!

Comment: You might be better to add a `hidden` field in the form and then everything would be POSTED

Comment: This may work better `<form method="POST" action="addNotes.php?id=" . <?php echo $idEleve; ?>">`

Comment: I have tried this <form method="POST" action="addNotes.php?id=" . <?php echo $idEleve; ?>"> but it doesn't work

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="addNotes.php?id=<?php echo $idEleve;?>">` Ops typo, sorry

Comment: Oh nice dude, thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

1) You can transfer it as a GET parameter to the next page in your form action attribute:

```php
<form method="POST" action="addNotes.php?id=" . <?= $idEleve ?>
```

Then receive it the same way:

```php
$idEleve = $_GET['id'];
```

2) Use a hidden input field

```php
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $idEleve ?>">
```

In that case it will be a part of your `$_POST` array:

```php
$_POST['id']
```